# Spring doesn't scan packages

Tags: java, spring

I have a repository, annotated with @Repository

```html
package com.jeppa.interfaces;

import com.jeppa.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUserEmailIgnoreCase(String useremail);
}
```

Part of my controller:

```html
package com.jeppa.controllers;

import com.jeppa.entities.ConfirmationToken;
import com.jeppa.entities.User;
import com.jeppa.interfaces.TokenRepository;
import com.jeppa.interfaces.UserRepository;
import com.jeppa.mail.EmailSenderService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UserAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmailSenderService emailSenderService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user){
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        return modelAndView;
    }

  //////////////
```

And, finnaly, my @SpringBootApplication:

```html
package com.jeppa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RunApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RunApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and i keep getting this error

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field userRepository in com.jeppa.controllers.UserAccountController
>   required a bean of type 'com.jeppa.interfaces.UserRepository' that
>   could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jeppa.interfaces.UserRepository'
>   in your configuration.

what am i doing wrong? here's my project structure:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDyIO.jpg)

Comment: The entity User doesn't have  Long id? You should use it in the interface generic instead of a <User, String> should be <User, Long>.

Comment: How do you add Spring Data to your project? Are you using the Spring Boot starter (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)?

Comment: spring-data-jpa in my dependencies

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BP6fDs7T

full list of my dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Boot, you should generally rely on Spring Boot starters to autoconfigure your dependencies. In case of Spring Data add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

into your pom file to autoconfigure Spring Data instead of directly relying on Spring Data (`spring-data-jpa`), which requires further manual configuration.

Also don't forget to add and configure an actual implementation as well (h2, jdbc, etc.)

Comment: thanks, i have a little progress, but now i'm getting
`Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
`

Comment: I think you have not configured your mysql connection properly, check: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-mysql-example/

Comment: nope, `Hibernate: alter table confirmation_token add constraint FKhjrtky9wbd6lbk7mu9tuddqgn foreign key (user_id) references user (user_id)`
i can see new tables in my db